# Spring Boot project error creating bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have the following code:

```
package com.frameworkonly.webapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.frameworkonly.webapp.domain.Employee;
import com.frameworkonly.webapp.service.EmployeeServiceInterface;

@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan("com.frameworkonly.webapp")
public class SpringBootDemoApplication {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeServiceInterface employeeServiceInterface;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I just started with `Spring Boot`. It gives me the following message and I don't know what it means:

```
Error creating bean with name 'springBootDemoApplication': Injection of 
autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire 
field: com.exemple.service.PatientServiceInterface 
com.example.SpringBootDemoApplication.patientServiceInterface; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [com.exemple.service.PatientServiceInterface] 
found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire 
candidate for this dependency.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `com.exemple.service` to the list of scanned packages assuming `PatientServiceInterface` is annotated with `@Service`

```
@ComponentScan({"com.frameworkonly.webapp","com.exemple.service"})
```